# Multiple fallbacks in ConTeXt font synonyms

Tags: fonts, context

I am trying to write a ConTeXt document, and need to replace multiple blocks of missing fonts with other fonts.  I am using the `fallbacks` key of `\definefontsynonym` to do so.  However, none of the missing fonts is replaced. How does one specify multiple fallbacks in ConTeXt?

Here is a file that illustrates the problem:

```
\usetypescript
  [pagella]

%% Unicode block `Miscellaneous Technical', range 2300--23FF,
%% http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf

\definefontfallback
  [BracketPieces]
  [XITSMath]
  [023B0,
   023B1]

%% Unicode block `Supplemental Mathematical Operators', range
%% 2A00--2AFF, http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2A00.pdf

\definefontfallback
  [SupplementalMathematicalOperators]
  [STIXGeneralRegular]
  [supplementalmathematicaloperators]

\definefontsynonym
  [Mono]
  [pagella]
  [fallbacks={BracketPieces,SupplementalMathematicalOperators}]

\enabletrackers
  [fonts.missing]

\setupbodyfont
  [pagella]

\starttext

\starttyping
Definition RightDistributivityTo (X Y Z : UU) :
  X × ⎰Y ⨿ Z⎱ → ⎰X × Y⎱ ⨿ ⎰X × Z⎱.
\stoptyping

\stoptext
```

Here is the relevant part of the output of the command `context file.tex`:

[image: PDF sans brackets and coproduct]

All the characters ⎰ ⨿ ⎱ are missing from the output.  The log file does *not* mention that the XITS and STIX fonts are being loaded.

However, if I use only one of the fallbacks, that fallback is used as expected.  For example, if I replace

```
[fallbacks={BracketPieces,SupplementalMathematicalOperators}]
```

with

```
[fallbacks=BracketPieces]
```

then I get the following PDF output, which displays the characters ⎰ and ⎱, and the log file mentions that the XITS font is being loaded.

[image]

A similar thing happens when I load only the other fallback.  I would appreciate any advice on how to use multiple font fallbacks in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't really understand the internals of font fallbacks. My answer is based on the `type-imp-euler.mkiv` typescript).

One option is to use a single name of the fallback. For example:

```
\definefontfallback[myfallbacks][XITSMath] [023B0, 023B1] 
\definefontfallback[myfallbacks][STIXGeneralRegular][supplementalmathematicaloperators]
\definefontsynonym [Mono] [pagella] [fallbacks=myfallbacks]
\setupbodyfont [pagella]

\enabletrackers [fonts.missing]

\starttext
\starttyping
Definition RightDistributivityTo (X Y Z : UU) :
  X × ⎰Y ⨿ Z⎱ → ⎰X × Y⎱ ⨿ ⎰X × Z⎱.
\stoptyping
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the answer works perfectly.  The plural `fallbacks` is a bit misleading.  All the examples I found in the sources use a single fallback.  It was instructive to look at the file `type-imp-euler.mkiv`.  Incidentally, what do the the `check` and `force` keys in `\definefontfallback` mean?

Comment: Found this just now in `font-col.mkiv`.check : only replace when present in replacement font (default: no);
% force : force replacent even when basefont has glyph  (default: yes)